# jQuery reindex array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this javascript / jQuery code:

```js
var json = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];



delete json[2]
console.log(json)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code delete the array key 2.
But I need an reindex after that, so that I can access the other 3 values like:

```
json[0]
json[1]
json[2]
```

How can I realize this ?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: You could try with `json.splice(2,1);`

Comment: `json.filter(j => true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to mutate the value you can simply filter the array

```
json.filter((i, idx) => idx !== 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `splice` instead of `delete` like below ([W3schools splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)):

```js
json.splice(target_index,1);
```

Please read the [Mozila page about the splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for more information.

Comment: @Skully after using splice, OP can use `json[0] - > json[2]` and get expected result

Answer (score 0):

you can reindex by simply using

```
json.filter(function(){return true;})
```

here is a working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#delete").click(function(){
   var json = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];



delete json[2]


console.log(json.filter(function(){return true;}))
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="delete">delete</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice method removes elements from an array and, if necessary, inserts new elements in their place, returning the deleted elements.

splice(start: number, deleteCount?: number)

```
json.splice(2, 1);
```